# Header pre-processed differently for each time it is #include(ed)

Tags: c, macros, header-files, pic, mplab

I have a source file that provides functionality to queue structs and pop/push them from an array.

For brevity, here is an example of how the `queue.c` file looks - There's some unrelated definitions omitted.

`queue.c`

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

queue_t queueCreate ( void ) {
    queue_t newQueue;
    newQueue.state = QUEUE_EMPTY;
    newQueue.front = 0;
    newQueue.count = 0;
    return newQueue;
}

/*
 *  Returns the first in from the queue passed to it if possible
 */
enum STATE_QUEUE queuePop ( queue_t *queue, queueElement_t *pop ) {
    // if queue isn't empty
    if( !queue_isEmpty(queue) ) {
        // get element at front of queue
        (*pop) = (*queue).queue[(*queue).front];

        // decrease count by 1 as element has been removed from queue
        (*queue).count--;

        // if front needs to wrap round the array
        if( (*queue).front == ( QUEUE_SIZE - 1 )) {
            (*queue).front = 0;
        } else {
            (*queue).front++;
        }

        //
        queueState(queue);

        // return the popped element to the calling function
        return QUEUE_OK;
    }
    return QUEUE_EMPTY;
}
```

Within the header file, i declare some types and use macros to change members within structures. When this code is used, #defines will specify the members within these sturctures. It's worth nothing that the contents of these macro-defining structures are never referenced by `queue.c`, but will be defined and used within calling source files

The header looks like this

`queue.h`

```
#ifndef QUEUE_SIZE
    #define QUEUE_SIZE 10
    #define QUEUE_COUNT_TYPE BYTE
#else
    #ifndef QUEUE_COUNT_TYPE
        #if QUEUE_SIZE > 255
            #define QUEUE_COUNT_TYPE int
        #else
            #define QUEUE_COUNT_TYPE BYTE
        #endif
    #endif
#endif

    /* Queued types */
#ifndef QUEUE_TYPE
    #define QUEUE_TYPE  struct { \
                            int data; \
                        }
#endif

    /* Queue type definitions*/
    typedef QUEUE_TYPE queueElement_t;

    typedef struct {
        QUEUE_COUNT_TYPE front;
        QUEUE_COUNT_TYPE count;
        queueElement_t queue[QUEUE_SIZE];
    } queue_t;

    /* Function Prototypes */
    queue_t             queueCreate ( void );
```

The calling source file will redefine QUEUE_TYPE to handle whatever structs are relevant.

I intend to wrap #include's with #defines to change the definition of the `queueElement_t` when this header file is used in multiple source files in my project.

Will i experience type errors because function names are the same, but handle different argument types? Or is there a way of making this work how I described?

**TL;DR If I include a header file in source files dotted throughout my project, that uses macros to change struct members that aren't explicitly accessed within the header file, will i experience any errors**

Comment: Read about what "*Header Guards*" are and why to use them.

Comment: @alk Thanks, i was aware of header guards, but didnt know that if the reasoning still applies if i was careful enough to avoid defining the same function twice within the same scope

Comment: this function: queue_t queueCreate ( void ) { returns a value/struct that is allocated on the local stack of the function.  This is a programming nono.  because the stack will probably be corrupted.  Much better to change the function to: queue_t* queueCreate ( void ) { then inside the function: this: queue_t newQueue; should be: queue_t* newQueue = malloc( sizeof queue_t );  which should be checked for not NULL then use the format: newQueue->field = ..;to fill in the fields.  The caller must now expect a pointer rather than a full queue_t struct to be returned.

Comment: the function queueCreate() should set every field to some known value, so this field: queueElement_t queue[QUEUE_SIZE]; 1) should probably be a pointer to a malloc'd area and initialized to NULL.  then instead of trying to define various sizes, you only have one size and the malloc of the field queueElement_t queue[] can be handled at run time.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case: yes. Because you have a function that is expected to use certain structure as a return. So when you attempt to use that structure from two different modules with different type definitions, you will find very interesting problems, related to ABI on the platform you are using.

You can, however, switch to using macros only, which would operate more like templates in C++. Small example:

```
#define QUEUE_TYPE(element, size) struct { int front, count; type queue[size]; } 
#define QUEUE_INIT(queue) queue.front = queue.count = 0;
#define QUEUE_SIZE(queue) sizeof(queue.queue)/sizeof(queue.queue[0])
#define QUEUE_PUSH(queue,val) \
    if (queue.front < QUEUE_SIZE(queue)) queue.queue[queue.front++] = val;
...

struct {
   QUEUE_TYPE(int,10) member;
} my_var;
...
QUEUE_INIT(my_var.member);
QUEUE_PUSH(my_var.member, 10)
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Does this still apply when different invocations of `queue.h` are never in the same scope?

Comment: @AustinGeorge Yes. Because you define symbols (function in your example), visible in global scope. If all you functions will be defined inside header as static, the global symbols will be removed, but there still possibility of redefining macros multiple times within module scope.

Comment: Thanks. I think this has come from a lack of experience of minding scope considering I've only used c for pic micros in the past. Trying to get my head round it, could I move all the element handling logic from the calling module to the queue module so to allow queue element structure differences between invocations of the queue module? Also, to keep the same functionality when elements are popped, id need to be able to change variables in global scope. I suppose I'd be able to do this with pointers assigned to each element to these global variables?

Comment: @AustinGeorge Yes, if you create a "common" queue structure component, you can define functions that operate with pointers (and sizes) as necessary. Then you can wrap those into macros to simplify API. For example, push/pop functions require pointer to queue, pointer to data, and size of data to copy. Macro can provide four arguments out of two by taking size of arguments.